# How to let the users input the filters in views

Tags: views

I have enabled Exposed Group Filters in views. When I set the option to "input required" no results are shown, also does not give me an option to input any filter from the selected option. All I get is an Apply button.

My Query is:

How do I let the users see all results in the view first, let the user input their filter criteria from the allowed list & then show them the results basis of the filters?

I have tried Better Exposed Filters, its still not giving me an option to input my query.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exposed filters are not displaying because the view is empty and therefore not rendering.  As per [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/559974), if you give your view something to display when it is empty (i.e. a `no results behaviour` setting), it will show your filters.

Then, if you really don't want to show 'no results' (which is what most people put in there) you *could* hide it wish CSS.

Comment: Hi Darvanen, Thank you for the input. My view does have content to display. If I disable the filter, I can see all results. however, if the filter is set up, the view comes up empty. I want to show all the results in the view to the user, which they then can filter out basis of the exposed filters. How do I achieve that?

Comment: By having your filters set to 'input required' you're blocking all content until they are filled out.  Please try putting something in the `no results behaviour`, just a bit of global text, you'll see what I mean.

If you want to show all results, then you need to turn off 'input required', or provide default values for the filters.